# How do I find the frame of a UIView in the context of a UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to place a `UIPopoverController` to display when a `UIButton` is tapped. However, the `UIButton` is placed within a `UIScrollView` and so its frame is offset by the scroll amount.

Is there an easy way of finding out a view's frame as it appears in the context of the screen? Or do I just need to do a subtraction between the `UIButton` frame and the `contentOffset` of the `UIScrollView`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific what exactly you want.As far as I can make out you want button's frame?

Comment: I want a button's frame as it appears in the root view, rather than its frame within just its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated` then you are already specifying the view that you are wanting to present from.  Just present the popover from 0,0 0,0 in your `UIButton`.

Comment: I did something very similar but thanks... I presented from the UIButton's rect and used the UIScrollView as the "inView"... :)